# Confidence interval for log transformed data (

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying trying to obtain confidence interval in original scale. I transformed my response variable to log(y). My question is will the confidence interval not be symmetric? I have provided the R code for back transforming the data into original scale and graph i obtain.

```
dat2$l <- exp(f1$coefficients[1] + f1$coefficients[2]*dat2$x)
dat2$l1 <- exp(f1$coefficients[1] + f1$coefficients[2]*dat2$x - 1.96 * summary(f1)$sigma)
dat2$l2 <- exp((f1$coefficients[1] + f1$coefficients[2]*dat2$x) + 1.96 * summary(f1)$sigma)
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this picture show you that they are not symmetric? If you look at `exp(log(10)+c(-1, 1))` you can see you get an interval that is not centered at 10. That's to be expected with this type of transformation.

Comment: The confidence interval won't be symmetric, and that's the correct behaviour. You see this a lot with binary outcomes. If you're still uncertain you could ask about why this is on https://stats.stackexchange.com.